# css - hover - effect only hovered item of that class instead of whole class

Tags: html, css, hover

I am doing this:

CSS :

```
.classname:hover { 
     color: green; 
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <span class="classname">Hi</span>
    <span class="classname">Bye</span>
</div>
```

When I hover, all the elements of that class appear in color green but i want only the hovered one to be in green

Comment: `<span class=".classname">` remove dot from class name

Comment: Also, best to use the hex value rather than the human readable name for the colour. IE: .classname:hover { color: #00FF00; }

Comment: See this fiddle:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3KM9e/)

Comment: First: With your example code, nothing will be green. You call a class in your css, which doesn't exist. So remove the dot (as @Deekey already said). Second: I don't understand your problem. When all the classnames are correct, the hovering will also work correct. With your code, only the hovered one will be colored!

Comment: thats a typo, ha ha, I put dot here in stackoverflow and not in my code :)

Comment: sory guys, its working now, its just another typo in the html that caused this. I started with span but ended with </somename>

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the dot (.) in the class:

```
<div>
    <span class="classname">Hi</span><span class="classname">Bye</span>
</div>
```

And as both spans have the same same class name in the example given they will both receive the hover class.

Answer (score 1):

CSS :

```
.class2:hover { 
    color: green; 
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <span class="class1">Hi</span><span class="class2">Bye</span><span class="class2">Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With that solution, you generate unnecessary css code. When both have the same CSS, only the hovered will be colored. Try it by your own:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KCJmy

Comment: :).. I understand that.. Considering `<span class=".classname"`, i gave two classes so that he understands, we can use different classname..